# Why do PMTs count differently over time?

Tags: experimental-physics

Plotting count rates against time there's clear evidence of the count rate starting off artificially high just after switching on, and then over time dropping in a curve that looks exponential, before it settles to a more constant count. Our PMT actually took about half an hour to reach this equilibrium, and then rates stayed pretty constant for the next hour, at which point we stopped taking data. We were able to observe the same behaviour during several repeats.

We haven't checked whether we actually have to expose the PMT to light for this to occur, or whether switching the high voltage off and back on again is enough.

I can't find any discussions of this online, so I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the direction of some literature on this subject!

Comment: You should define PMT.  Otherwise, someone who isn't familiar with that acronym has no idea what you are counting.

Comment: Just guessing: Could be some transient of a heat sink being switched on.

Comment: Leo has a section on the ways PMT behavior depends on its recent history. My copy has gone with some student to who knows where so I can't look it up just now.

Comment: @dmckee That is an excellent book, thank you! Although it doesn't describe the reason behind this particular behaviour.